# formik, pass Field's prop to children?

Tags: reactjs, formik

Below, when I use `component={RadioButton}`, RadioButton gets `id, label` fine.

But if I grab the definition of `RadioButton` and pass it as `render` prop of `Field`, `id, label` is not passed along.

```
   <Field
     component={RadioButton}
     name="number_operation"
     id="2" // this gets passed fine
     label="2"
   />
   <Field
     name="number_operation"
     id="more" // this dosn't get passed 
     label="more"
     render={({
       field: { name, value, onChange, onBlur },
       id,
       label,
       className,
       ...props
     }) => {

       return (
         <React.Fragment>
```

RadioButton

```
 const RadioButton = ({
   field: { name, value, onChange, onBlur },
   id,
   label,
   className,
   ...props
 }) => {
   return (
```

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox with the code?

Comment: Render method only passes down FormikBag props which dont pass any custom props